# Group items by types: replace nested for loops with reduce

Tags: javascript, performance, functional-programming

I have a working code that groups items by their type values. The types can be one or multiple, however they are always returned as an array.

To illustrate: if an item has types with values `type1` and `type2`, it should be included in both `type1` and `type2` properties of the resulting grouped object.

Although the code works, I was wondering if it would be possible to rewrite it without using nested `for` loops, to make it more aligned with the principles of functional programming, ideally using `reduce`. Since the data sets are not too large, performance is a secondary consideration, but should be taken into account if possible.

The code is as follows. `getTypes` is added primarily to show how the types are extracted and ideally shouldn't be changed.

```js
const items = [{
    name: 'First item',
    types: [{
        value: 'type1',
      },
      {
        value: 'type2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Second item',
    types: [{
        value: 'type1',
      },
      {
        value: 'type3',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Third item',
    types: [{
        value: 'type1',
      },
      {
        value: 'type2',
      },
    ],
  },
];

const getTypes = item => item.types.map(type => type.value);

const groupedItems = {};

for (const item of items) {
  for (const type of getTypes(item)) {
    groupedItems[type] = [...(groupedItems[type] || []), item];
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(groupedItems, null, 4));
```

Code output:

```
{
    "type1": [
        {
            "name": "First item",
            "types": [
                {
                    "value": "type1"
                },
                {
                    "value": "type2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Second item",
            "types": [
                {
                    "value": "type1"
                },
                {
                    "value": "type3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Third item",
            "types": [
                {
                    "value": "type1"
                },
                {
                    "value": "type2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "type2": [
        {
            "name": "First item",
            "types": [
                {
                    "value": "type1"
                },
                {
                    "value": "type2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Third item",
            "types": [
                {
                    "value": "type1"
                },
                {
                    "value": "type2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "type3": [
        {
            "name": "Second item",
            "types": [
                {
                    "value": "type1"
                },
                {
                    "value": "type3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure why you want to change perfectly readable code to use reduce? JavaScript seems to lack "array comprehensions" ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions )  / "object comprehensions" (not sure about the latter term), so till it will get those using for loops looks perfect to me.

Comment: @RomanSusi I was just wondering if it were possible to make this code more concise with `reduce`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Poor memory usage

Javascript has managed memory. That means it does all the hard work of allocating and releasing memory, which is great (managing memory manually is a real pain).

But this useful feature comes with a down sides...

- Managed memory environments are inherently slow,
- Managed memory environments encourage very poor memory usage patterns

### Looking at your memory and CPU usage.

In your code you create a total of 9 arrays, keeping only 3 of them. (using the data example you provided)

Each time you add an item to a group you create a new array, that must be iterated over when you copy the existing group. `groupedItems[type] = [...(groupedItems[type] || []), item]`

There are only 6 type values yet you iterate over them 12 times. Once each with `item.types.map(type => type.value);` and then again with `for (const type of getTypes(item))`

For the 6 items you add to the 3 groups your code needed 16 iterations.

### Less overhead

The example avoids copying the item.types array for each item and assigns a new array to new groups. If a group has been defined the item added is pushed rather than copy the whole array.

The resulting code only needs 6 iterations executing in half the time and using several times less memory

```
function groupTypes(items) {
    const groups = {};
    for (const item of items) {
        for (const {value: type} of item.types) {
            groups[type] ? groups[type].push(item) : groups[type] = [item];
        }
    }
    return groups;
}
```

Or slightly quicker by avoiding the copy of the `type.value` string to to the variable `type`

```
function groupTypes(items) {
    const grps = {};
    for (const item of items) {
        for (const type of item.types) {
            grps[type.value] ? grps[type.value].push(item) : grps[type.value] = [item];
        }
    }
    return grps ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Would the implementation change if we had no control over `getTypes` and just knew that it returns an array of type values?

Comment: @Clarity In the first example you would replace the inner loop  with `for (const type of getTypes()) {` If the function `getTypes` is inhouse you can suggest politely that such functions should be generators eg `getTypes(item) { for(const {value} of item.types) { yield value } }` saving the need to use a temp array to transport data. For more on generators https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator

Comment: Great, thanks, didn't know about performance benefits of generators in this case.